# Weird behaviour of img tags

Tags: css, html, grid, image

I have some problem when creating a grid of div on a page, but each cell in the grid can have different type of elements in it like `<div></div>` or `<img/>`. The grid is being generated but it is a distorted when few of the elements of the cells differ.

Here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/22fD6/1/) of the problem.

But when you replace the `img` tags with `divs` it works fine.
Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply `vertical-align:top` to `div` elements. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/AQnS4/

Comment: Thanks, But what was the reason of this problem, I mean what was the difference when not using vertical-align?

Comment: @DigvijayYadav The default vertical-align is baseline. This is how the image and text would look if you just put them next to each other without the grid.

Comment: @Neil: Ok, So does it means the vertical position and height of the element will start from there?

Comment: @DigvijayYadav Each inline/inline-block element tries to align itself within its parent or line according to its vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use `vertical-align:top;` to have your elements scrunch up to the top line rather than start from the base of the last one. http://jsfiddle.net/22fD6/5/